# Save image from expo assets to user device but first let the user select the target folder

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I have researched a lot , even used ChatGTP3 solutions ( which by the way are cool ) but nothing works .

---

So i will explain my case ( i am targeting android ) :

1. Inside the local expo assets i have 30 images

[image]

i want to allow the user to download this images to his device for whatever reason so i have provided a download button :

[image]

**When you press the download button i want the user to be able to pick the folder where he wants to save the image and then save it** that's it here is an example of many codes i have tried it just doesn't work :

```
    import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'

    const saveToPhone = async () => {
    try {
        // Assuming that you have a file called '30.jpg' in your Expo assets folder
        const fileUri = Asset.fromModule(require('../../../assets/images/motivational/30.jpg')).uri

        // Let the user pick a folder to save the file to
        const saveDir = await FileSystem.getDocumentDirectoryAsync()

        // Create a new file in the save directory with the same name as the file in assets
        const savePath = `${saveDir}/imageName.jpg`

        // Copy the file from assets to the save directory
        await FileSystem.copyAsync({ from: fileUri, to: savePath })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I have tried so many codes for days i can't find out how to do that .I am using latest expo sdk 47 .

---

Update 24/12/2022

After using @proto answer:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker'

const saveToPhone = async () => {
  try {
    // Assuming that you have a file called '30.jpg' in your Expo assets folder
    const fileUri = Asset.fromModule(require('../../../assets/images/motivational/30.jpg')).uri

    // Let the user pick a folder to save the file to
    const saveDir = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()

    // Create a new file in the save directory with the same name as the file in assets
    const savePath = `${saveDir.uri}/imageName.jpg`

    // Copy the file from assets to the save directory
    await FileSystem.copyAsync({ from: fileUri, to: savePath })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
 LOG  [Error: Location 'http://192.168.1.13:8081/assets/assets/images/motivational/30.jpg?platform=android&hash=0cf4bfe9c8ccb915c1d43a641d662544?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false' isn't readable.]
```

Comment: I have posted also a similar question but for `sharing the expo-asset file` here in case you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910358/share-image-from-expo-assets-using-expo-sharing-produces-mysterious-errors

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional module called `DocumentPicker` from `expo-document-picker`. Instead of getting directory directly, try selecting a document and extract its path.

Something like this :

```
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker'

const saveDir = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()
const savePath = `${saveDir.uri}/imageName.jpg`
```

So now the code should look like this :

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker'

const saveToPhone = async () => {
  try {
    // Assuming that you have a file called '30.jpg' in your Expo assets folder
    const fileUri = Asset.fromModule(require('../../../assets/images/motivational/30.jpg')).uri

    // Let the user pick a folder to save the file to
    const saveDir = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()

    // Create a new file in the save directory with the same name as the file in assets
    const savePath = `${saveDir.uri}/imageName.jpg`

    // Copy the file from assets to the save directory
    await FileSystem.copyAsync({ from: fileUri, to: savePath })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am testing it right now :) Can you please help me on this new very similar question too :) ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74910358/share-image-from-expo-assets-using-expo-sharing-produces-mysterious-errors

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I answered it, let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have edited my question with the error i get after successfully selecting the saveDir using your solution :)

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS try changing to ``const savePath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/imageName.jpg``. See if this works.

Comment: I tried and the problem occurs during `// Copy the file from assets to the save directory
   await FileSystem.copyAsync({ from: fileUri, to: savePath })` looks like expo not allowed to read for some reason . I am using emulator of course.

Comment: Then we don't use `copyAsync` at all. Replace that line with these two :
`const fileContents = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri)`
  &  then 
`await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(savePath, fileContents)`.
See if this works

Comment: Still same error that i have added on the question :( `can't read the original file from the uri`) . I will export now the project to apk to see if it's an emulator problem when running locally .... that's so strange . Thank's for helping by the way :)