# Share image from `expo assets` using expo-sharing produces mysterious error

Tags: react-native, expo

**I am using latest expo-47 with dev-client i have taken care of creating custom dev-client that includes the libraries that i am using on the given code.**

---

So i will explain my case ( i am targeting android ) :

1. Inside the local expo assets i have 30 images

[image]

I want to allow the user to **share** the images using `expo-sharing` but i am getting error [ see end of post ]

[image]

Below is an example of many codes i have tried it just doesn't work :

```
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing'

async function shareImage(imageURI) {
    try {
        await Sharing.shareAsync(require('../../../assets/images/motivational/36.jpg'))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

The error is the below :

```
[Error: Argument of an incompatible class: class java.lang.Double cannot be passed as an argument to parameter expecting class java.lang.String.]
```

What is this supposed to mean ?

[image]

**I HAVE of course verified that the image exists on the given path**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `require` statement from `.shareAsync`.

Write it like this :
`await Sharing.shareAsync('../../../assets/images/motivational/36.jpg')`

-OR-
Define the path before hand and call it as
`await Sharing.shareAsync(imageURI)`.

Let me know if this solves it.

Comment: After using your answer  i am getting this error :
`[Error: Only local file URLs are supported (expected scheme to be 'file', got 'null'.]
`

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS hmm, can you rename the file `36.jpg` to a string value like `test.jpg` and use it with require flag as earlier. Something like `await Sharing.shareAsync(require('../../../assets/images/motivational/test.jpg'))
`. See if renaming the file works

Comment: Still the same i changed the file name to `something.jpg` and getting the error `[Error: Argument of an incompatible class: class java.lang.Double cannot be passed as an argument to parameter expecting class java.lang.String.]`

Comment: how is this possible i am wondering .